# Java - matrix implementation using a tree data structure

Tags: java, tree

Is there any method to implement a matrix using a tree data structure? I have thought about it. You could implement an array using a tree data structure but in case of the matrices, how can you also keep track of the number of rows and columns?
Any ideas?

Comment: What concrete problem are you trying to solve? This sound very much like "is it possible to build a house with bananas?". We could try to imagine a solution, but what would be the point?

Answer (score 0):

For a square matrix `2^n x 2^n` you could represent it by a quadtree (each node has pointers to NW, NE, SE, SW subtrees). You could represent other sizes of matrix (even rectangular) if some of the pointers to subtrees are null. Null pointers mean that a sub-square of the matrix is empty. I'm not sure what use such a data structure would be ... maybe in image processing?